# How to avoid rerender of list in a infinite scroll like situation in React?

Tags: reactjs, list

So suppose you have a list that is growing with products being added as you scroll down(creating your own infinite scroll). Everytime the state of the list gets updated it rerenders the whole list. so it renders products 1-10; 1-20;1-30;1-40; How can we make it so it keeps the previous values but only renders the new 10 coming in without having to re render the whole thing?

Comment: Simple Increase the data to your listItems and the scroll position will stay the same. That is so the react work.

Comment: @Alen.Toma I dont think this answers my question. If I want to make an infinite scroll myself, everytime I load more products the whole list is rerendered. I want to avoid rerendering the previous items that were already rendered and only render the new ones on top of the exisitng ones

Comment: I'm not an expert, but seems it's a pass through model, which means there's no cache in terms of all the fetched items. To be honest, i never heard there's a cache for render in React. You can take a look at some of the source code, https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component/blob/master/src/index.tsx

Comment: I could write this and prove that what I say do work. But you have to present us with code first. Try it your self first and if it did not work come back and show us what You wrote and we will see why its not working for you.